# Option style with grant date

Tags: options, american-options, european-options, bermudan

The following option exercise style is somewhere between American and European:

*There is a fixed **grant date** $N_1$ at which you determine at which date $N_2>N_1$ the option will be exercised.*

So once the grant date $N_1$ arrives, the option becomes European, i.e., you have to commit yourself to when the option will be exercised. But the choice of $N_2$ may depend on the history of stock prices up to time $N_1$.

Perhaps this is Bermudan or Verde. Is there a standard or succinct way to describe it?